# Boolean with wireframe on mesh

Tags: wireframe

I have a mesh, then I copy the mesh and put the wireframe modifier on it.
Then I select my original mesh and set boolean modifier with the wireframed mesh with the "difference" option. I then hide the wireframe mesh.

Here I expect the wireframe mesh to "carve into" my original mesh at the edge lines. However, this is not working.

1. When I use the difference option it just acts as a union, the two meshes are merged together (See first image)
2. When I use Union the wireframe does "carve into" my original mesh, but it makes holes in it (see image). I want the mesh to still be "watertight". (See second image)

Does anyone know a good way to get the effect that I want?

[image][image: asasas]

Comment: Try to reduce the offset so the wireframe actually intersects properly, then use *Difference* in the *Boolean* modifier on the other sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is something like what you're after...

[image]

- Select all edges, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel, by width, with a moderate even number of segments (here,6)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Keypad -</kbd> reduce the selection back to the original latitudes and longitudes
- <kbd>O</kbd> turn on proportional editing, Connected, Sphere fall-off, small radius
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> scale along normals.
- Select the smallest 'large' face, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> select similar by area > 'Greater Than' to select all the large faces, and <kbd>I</kbd> inset them a little..

[image]

- With  Autosmooth switched on, maybe have a play with the new Weighted
  Normal modifier, by face area, to get the look you want without
  subdivision.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you wish to use Boolean modifier apply it to the original sphere, using the wireframe one to modify.

Select the non-wireframe sphere. Set **Carve**, **Difference** and select the other sphere in the modifier panel. Apply. Delete the wireframe sphere.
[image]

Then use <kbd>Shift+G</kbd> to remove undesired faces shown.